# Django 1.11 Unexpected change in generation of password reset token

Tags: python, django

I have been successful in generating password reset links and sending them to mail using django builtin password reset and also used my own templates wherever needed.

Above was the case when I implemented it in my test project (just to not break my actual project). but when I copy pasted my codes from test project to actual project, there was change in generation of reset password links

Token when was working in my test project

> http://localhost:8000/reset/MQ-4mv-a71bc30f3eddfc12bd21/

Token when was working in my actual project

> http://localhost:8000/reset/Mg/4mv-66daf7703ee57c98aaa8/

There is a change MQ- and Mg/

My problem:

1) I am unable to match the regular expression in the URL and show my template instead of django default template which is being shown

```
url(r'^reset/password/success/$', AuthHandler().reset_success, name="auth.success"),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',AuthHandler().reset_password, name="password_reset_confirm"),
url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete,name="auth.complete"),
```

In view.py

```
def forgot_password(self, request):
    # Forgot password form
    try:
        error_flag = True
        if request.method == "GET":
            error_flag = False

        form = auth.ForgotPassword()

        return auth_views.password_reset(
            request, template_name='forgot_password.html',
            extra_context={'form': form, 'error': error_flag},
            password_reset_form=auth.EmailValidationOnForgotPassword,
            post_reset_redirect='auth.success',
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def reset_success(self, request):

    # Reset email sent to email
    try:
        return auth_views.password_reset_done(request, template_name='reset_password_success.html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
def reset_password(self, request, uidb64, token):

    # Reset password page
    try:
        reset_form = auth.ResetPassword()  # template_name='te/reset_password.html',
        return auth_views.password_reset_confirm(
            request,
            template_name='reset_passwword_success.html',
            post_reset_redirect='auth.success', current_app=None,
            extra_context=None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The problem is I am unable to get into reset_password function page and hence show my template, where django default is being shown. but I was able to when working in my test project ( used '-' in regex of url there)

2) Why is Django generating two completely different types of links one with  / and other without it. ( In my knowledge no hash should have / in it).

Comment: I hate to be the guy that suggests a package instead of the answer to your question but...  You might try django-password-reset. I've used and and it's very simple to get running.

Comment: I tend to agree with the idea that a hash, at least a hash used in a URL, should not have a `/` in it. Perhaps you could take this question to the Django mailing list, or file a ticket about it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this regex do it?

```
r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$'
```

From this blog: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Comment: ya, after I tweaked the form for resetting it is working with the above regex, but my main doubt is why it generated two different regexes !! and also with '/' in hash

Comment: No idea, honestly.